# People rejects edit without any reason where question edit is meaningful?

Tags: discussion, support, magento2

I know this question is asked many time but I need to draw an attention of moderators. 
I have made one change. Question was about exporting Magneto 2 orders.
But title of that question was **"Script for export products"**

And I checked answer as well answer is about to export orders in magneto  2. 
So I made a change in question title you can review that here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/118729

Still, some people have rejected the edit.

So  I don't know what is mean by the user one who rejects such changes which is truly acceptable!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that this edit made the title more clear and the majority of the reviewers agreed, so don't worry.

The one reviewer who disagreed might have not looked closely enough because on first sight it doesn't look like a very useful edit: only minor change, redundant adding of "Magento 2" in the title (this is what tags are for) and it's an old question with few views. There are different opinions if the latter actually matters (see [Is the date of the question relevant when reviewing suggested edits?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/899/is-the-date-of-the-question-relevant-when-reviewing-suggested-edits)) but I tend to approve minor edits more likely if the question is fresh (or still popular).